# .data section in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am trying to learn assembly language and couldn't understand the concept of declaring global variables through .data section .When you declare a variable in .data section , the assembler/linker would map it to a memory location. But how does it know about the free memory available while compiling the source code. If the memory allocation is done during runtime ,then how does the program know where to allocate memory, since we are not doing that in the code.

Comment: Metadata in the executable tells the kernel's program-loader how many bytes of data to map into memory.  For an OS like Windows, which uses virtual memory to give every process its own address space, it's very simple: the linker knows the whole 4GiB address space is available (or at least the low 2GiB of it, with 32-bit kernels reserving the high part).

Answer (score 3):

> But how does it know about the free memory available while compiling the source code.

When compiling; it uses a very simple allocator to create space for pieces of code and data in sections, where that allocator could be as simple as "`offset = section.size; section.size += object.size`". Later (when linking), when the final sizes of sections are known (and the address for the start of each section is known), it goes back and converts these offsets into addresses by adding "address for the start of the section" to each "offset in section".

Then the details for sections (their address in memory, size, attributes, where they are in the executable file) are stored in the executable file's header.

When the executable file is loaded, the OS uses the executable file's header to figure out which parts of the file get loaded/mapped where. Typically the OS (or the programming language's library) will also keep track of which areas of the virtual address space are used for what; so that if/when the program allocates more virtual address space (using functions like `VirtualAlloc()` on Windows or `mmap()` on Unix clones) it can allocate virtual space that isn't already used (by sections, etc).

Finally; when the program starts running (possibly in "default startup code" that the linker included for you) it will probably allocate virtual space for the program's heap, and then use that virtual space to set up dynamic memory management (e.g. `malloc()` or `new` or whatever makes sense for the language and its libraries).

*Note 1: Compiling and linking isn't quite that simple (e.g. the allocator used to create space in sections would have to worry about things like alignment too).*

*Note 2: Executable loaders aren't that simple (e.g. they also load/map shared libraries and do dynamic linking).*

*Note 3: Most modern systems use "address space layout randomization" (in an attempt to improve security), so the final addresses (used by code, data) may be determined (from offsets in sections) by the executable loader (as part of dynamic linking) and not fully determined by the linker itself.*